# Gradle: how to implicitly run build task before custom task?

Tags: gradle, build, gradle-plugin

I am writing a plugin for Gradle. I spent a lot of time and do not know how to solve the problem correctly.
I need automatically run build task before running my own task. DependsOn is not suitable as it tightly binds tasks, and I want to take advantage of Gradle's input, output principle. What commonly can be triggered in project as input paramether for my task for such behaviours?.

gradle customTask

result:

:build
+----:customTask

My castomTask uses project.configuration() and I try mark it as @InputFile but it dosent trigger build task.